# R exports csv file with extra rows than what it is supposed to have

Tags: r

I wrote a csv file with R, and got extra rows than what it is supposed to have.
[image]

Below is the code I used to save my file.

`write.csv(df.raw.file2, "raw_file.csv")`

In R, the data fame that I would like to save has 4261 rows, but there are 6009 rows in the output file with those highlighted rows that should be not in there.
[image]

It seems that R wrote those rows with pretty `protein names` into multiple rows. A screenshot of those rows is attached.

[image]

Here is one example of those pretty long `protein names`.

```
"5-AMP-activated protein kinase catalytic subunit alpha-1\n2\t[12]\t\tQ13131\tAAPK1_HUMAN\t16\t21\t30.1\t7.40\t4.2e-13\t564.8242\t2\t-0.042\tVPFLVAETPR\t\t\tY20210222-10_FTMSms2hcd\t37.694\t14146\t92556\t31.5\t4.8e-7\t1\tHUMAN\t5-AMP-activated protein kinase catalytic subunit alpha-1"
```

Does anyone know how to avoid exporting those unwanted rows? Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Check how many rows you have in a plain text editor (Rstudio code window, Notepad++, etc) and see if you can identify on which row it starts to look strange, and how many total rows of raw text you have. Using Excel will not be overly helpful in debugging this.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for your reply! The values in some rows seem to be pretty long, which is why R wrote those rows into multiple rows instead of one row.  I will add more details below.

Comment: They will always be written to multiple rows, because you have literal line breaks (`\n`) inside that column in R. Usually quoting the fields (which R's `write.csv` should do by default), will allow you to read the file back into R no problems. e.g: `read.csv(text='column 1,"column 2 part 1\npart2"', header=FALSE)` How other programs handle that text/quoting on import needs to be solved at the level of that program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `'\n'` from the protein names before writing it to csv.

```
df.raw.file2$protein_names <- gsub('\n', '', df.raw.file2$protein_names)

#If '\n' is present in all the columns use lapply
#df.raw.file2[] <- lapply(df.raw.file2, function(x) gsub('\n', '', x))

write.csv(df.raw.file2, 'raw_file.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```